# Woocommerce - How to change the text next to star rating

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Thank for reading my issue.
Please help that which code snippets can let me change the text "customer reviews" in html below:

```html
<a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow"><span class="count">1</span> customer reviews</a>
```

I had try this but it not work for me.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text ) {
    if ( '**customer reviews**' === $translated_text ) {
        $translated_text = '**reviews**';
    }
    return $translated_text;
} );
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little complex so I'll try to use plain English where possible. If you do a search through the WooCommerce plugin for the string you need, you'll find this:

```
_n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' )
```

...which means you can't use the *gettext* filter, you need the *ngettext* one instead as this is a more complex internationalization function:

```
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'bbloomer_modify_n_customer_reviews', 9999, 5 );

function bbloomer_modify_n_customer_reviews( $translation, $single, $plural, $number, $domain ) {
    $translation = preg_replace( '%s customer reviews', '%s reviews', $translation );
    return $translation;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made some changes and it work for me.

`add_filter( 'ngettext', 'bbloomer_modify_n_customer_reviews', 9999, 5 );
function bbloomer_modify_n_customer_reviews( $translation, $single, $plural, $number, $domain ) {
    if ( '%s customer reviews' === $translation ) {
        $translation = '%s reviews';
   }
   return $translation;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress for changing any text showing on front end or on admin you can change with `add_filter('gettext', '_translateTextCustom', 100, 3 );`

Try below code snippet

```php
add_filter('gettext', '_translateTextCustom', 999, 3 );
function _translateTextCustom( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  global $pagenow, $post_type;

  if ( !is_admin() && "customer reviews" === $text && 'woocommerce' === $domain )
  {
    $translated_text =  __( 'reviews', $domain );
  }
  return $translated_text;
}
```

1. **`global $pagenow`** - You will access all php pages with this global variable.

> `in_array( $pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php']`

2. **`global $post_type`** - You will access all post types which you want conditionally.

> `'product' === $post_type || 'page' === $post_type || 'post' === $post_type`